# SSIS FileNameColumnName output value incorrect

Tags: ssis

In a Flat File Source in SSIS I am trying to use the FileNameColumnName property (from Advanced Properties) to populate a field in a database.  It seems quite straightforward - I simply gave it a name and mapped it to a field in my OLE DB.  The problem is, however, that it DB field is populated with the letter 'C', and nothing more.

My data type is varchar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ooops.  Sorted it out - had to change the output to Unicode (nvarchar in the OLE DB).  Thanks!